# How can I select the rows that appear before a specific value?

Tags: date, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have a table with the following information:

```
CREATE TABLE A (
    ID int,
    start_date varchar(255),
    effdate varchar(255),
    enddate varchar(255),
    lead_effdate varchar(255),
    value varchar(255),
    source varchar(255),
    lead_source varchar(255)
);
INSERT INTO A
VALUES (1,"12/01/2013","12/01/2013","30/07/2014","31/07/2014",4,"REM","REM"),
(1,"31/07/2014","31/07/2014","04/09/2014","12/09/2014",4,"REM","REM"),
(1,"12/09/2014","12/09/2014","12/04/2015","13/04/2015",4,"REM","REM"),
(1,"13/04/2015","13/04/2015","01/01/2016","02/01/2016",4,"REM","REM"),
(1,"02/01/2016","02/01/2016","11/03/2016","13/03/2016",4,"REM","REM"),
(1,"13/03/2016","13/03/2016","22/04/2017","10/07/2016",4,"REM","GS"),
(1,"10/07/2016","10/07/2016",null,"23/04/2017",4,"GS","REM"),
(1,"23/04/2017","23/04/2017","05/05/2018","06/05/2018",4,"REM","REM"),
(1,"06/05/2018","06/05/2018","09/11/2019","10/11/2019",4,"REM","REM"),
(1,"10/11/2019","10/11/2019",null,null,4,"REM",null);

select * from A
order by start_date
```

I would like to delete all rows from source = GS to the lowest row in the table. The order is given by start_date as you can see.

I tried to use a row_number() over(partition by... to create negative and positive values around GS, but I couldn't figure this index. How would you solve it?

Comment: the data doesn'rt make sense, varchar have to be in quotes, also save dates always as date not as varchar and format it when you select it only

Comment: `all rows from source = GS to the bottom`? Of what order are you talking? All rows with `source >= 'GS'`?

Comment: That's not valid SQL. Tip: Use the [`DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html) type for date values, and encode as [ISO-8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), as in `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Comment: Hint: What does `12/01/2013` evaluate to? Consider `SELECT 12/01/2013`.

Comment: Sorry about the table. I corrected the values and it should be working now.

Comment: It is my own logic that tells me to remove all rows after GS appears. When you recreate the table, you'll find the value GS at a specific row. From that row onwards , I want to delete all other rows (the GS one included). You can see that there is also a date order by looking at start date.

Comment: Tables represent unordered sets of data. Even if the row *happens* to appear at a certain position when selecting the data without an `ORDER BY` clause, there is nothing to guarantee that position. If you want to find the row position in the list of rows ordered by start_date, then you must explicitly say so. A date literal in MySQL (and standard SQL for that matter) is `DATE '2020-12-10'` by the way.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner The table has the order I wanted to show. I'm not aware that the values will be shuffled when using this structure in DataBricks.

Comment: This is true for all relational databases: Only `ORDER BY` guarantees an ordered result. Without `ORDER BY` the order is arbitrary.

Answer (score 0):

If by "to the bottom" you mean "a larger id" then you can use `join` in the `delete`:

```
delete a
    from a join
         (select max(id) as gs_id
          from a
          where source = 'GS'
         ) aa
         on a.id > aa.gs_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to select all rows with a date equal to or newer than a row with source = 'GS'. As there can be multiple rows with `source = 'GS'` you must decide for one row. Probably the first or the last.

```
delete from a where start_date >= (select min(start_date) from a where source = 'GS');
```

Comment: delete is not supported by Databricks. Do you know another method?

Comment: I don't know databricks. Your question is tagged `mysql`. My answer is a standard-compliant `DELETE` statement that works in MySQL and about any other RDBMS.

Comment: ... And I just googled `databricks` and `delete`: https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/delta-delete-from.html Looks like it *is* supported.

Comment: Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: DELETE destination only supports Delta sources. As you can see Databricks doesn't support delete unless the table is stored in Delta source, which I cannot do.

Comment: Okay. Then I can't help. Sorry. I know SQL and several RDBMS. I don't know Databricks.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: I think MySQL does not support reopening the target table in the `where` clause of a `delete` statement. You probably need to write that as a `join` instead.